# Can you identify this function?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

Can you identify the function depicted below?

*Edit: this is actually a function over nonnegative integers with the points interpolated by straight lines. I hope this helps.*

[image: Mystery function]

Comment: So are you looking for a mathematical function $f(x)$, or the description of something that causes it (e.g., the heart rate pattern of a llama in labor)?

Comment: Hehe its a function $f(x)$ like you said

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [A043537](https://oeis.org/A043537), the number of distinct digits in the base-10 form of n. The peaks in the first part of the graph are from the multiples of 11. After it reaches 100, there is a plateau for 102-109, then it drops for 110 and 111, and goes back up for 120. After that, the dips are for numbers with two digits the same.